# Does anyone know how to or managed to upgrade to Lollipop a Samsung Galaxy Tab E?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, updates, samsung-galaxy-tab

I am asking specifically for the following models of Samsung Galaxy Tab E which seems to be stuck on KitKat(4.4) without being able to upgrade to Lollipop(5.0) ?

- SM-T113NU
- SM-T561
- SM-T560

Does anyone know if it will be EVER possible to upgrade it?  Is there any fundamentally truth that forbid to do the upgrade ?

Comment: Call me harsh, but you have yourself to blame for buying Spreadtrum-powered devices...

Comment: I've found a firmware for SM-T560, Android version 5.1.1 :  T560NUUEU1AOK1_T560NUXAC1AOK1_XAC

Comment: @esQmo mine is just Tab E SM-T560 without NU at the end. Any upgrade possible from KitKat 4.4.4?

Comment: I am looking forward to doing an upgrade for my SM-T560. Today I found Samsung realease for open source android for phones and tablets... http://opensource.samsung.com/reception.do  .... I download the files for my tablet ( phones ) but don't understand how to compile all this, first on what OS do I need to compile, on another machine, or on the Tablet.... how to upload the result to the tablet.... any help will be apreciated !!!! thanks!